# How to keep public static variable from becoming unassigned?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to have a Dictionary `dict` available to a worksheet event handler, so I've stored it in a module `GlobalVariables` as follows:

```
Public dict As Dictionary
```

`dict` is initialized in the `Workbook_Open` event:

```
Private Sub workbook_open()

Set dict = New Dictionary
dict.Add "abc", "def"

End Sub
```

This is the event handler in `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub worksheet_beforedoubleclick(ByVal target As Range, cancel As Boolean)

If dict Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "nothing"
Else
    Debug.Print "not nothing"
End If

End Sub
```

When I first open the workbook and double-click on a cell in `Sheet1`, `dict` is not `Nothing`.  But If I put a breakpoint on this line:

```
If dict Is Nothing Then
```

and then End the sub after it halts at the breakpoint, then the next time I double-click and reach the same breakpoint, `dict` is `Nothing`.  It seems that ending the `_beforedoubleclick` sub prematurely has the effect of unassigning `dict`.  How can I keep this from happening?  I'd like to have this public variable keep its value while I'm debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't keep it from happening. If you need public vars (other than consts) to be assigned when you run code, you need to call an initialisation method at the start of whatever code you're running to check whether they are assigned, and if not, assign them.